# What is the difference between package import and normal import in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Going through some flutter source code and found two different types of imports.

What is the difference between the two and which one is better ?

```
#1
import 'folder/filename.dart';

#2
import 'package:projectname/folder1/folder2/folder/filename.dart';
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no performance differences or anything like that.

But.. it is better to use package paths because you won't need to edit all your imports in case you move your file to another location (as they're not relative paths).

Answer (score 3):

Saying that there is no difference at all might be tricky. Because importing files as packages in some place and as simple files in another, dart will consider them two different namespaces. So it can cause type conflicts. The safe way to do it is to choose one method to do it and stick to it.

Comment: This happened in "The boring Flutter development show -  Technical debt and streams - Time(43:00) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fahC3ky_zW0". I don't Know if it has been fixed in dart, but I have always used the complete package import ever since then.

Comment: that's what Matt says. Funnily enough, Filip says the opposite :) btw, here the timestamped link: https://youtu.be/fahC3ky_zW0?t=2553